# (How) can I provide a custom class to set up pages in Wicket?

Tags: wicket

I would like to change the way Wicket instantiates my `Page` instance for a subset of URLs. Normally, I would map a class to a URL with `mount()`, in which case Wicket chooses one of the available constructors on that class and instantiates it.

A part of my application are simple CRUD operations that have a lot in common between different entity types. I have factored out the common aspects into some factory and helper classes and now I'm left with a class hierarchy for my pages which looks like this:

```
                          TemplatePage
                               | 
                       AbstractEntityPage
              |                                 |
      AbstractVenuePage                 AbstractEventPage
      |                |                |                |
ViewVenuePage    EditVenuePage    ViewEventPage    EditEventPage
```

I would like to cut the last two levels, because the hierarchy starts to sprawl as more entity types are added and there's very little code left in those classes which could be factored out easily to more generic objects.

It's rather easy to transform `AbstractEntityPage` into a class `EntityPage` that gets specific components plugged in place as needed. I would normally use a Builder to do this, but I'm not sure how I would tell Wicket to use it? I couldn't find a hook for that in the API docs.

Comment: What are the page variations that you need to handle. Editor/viewer for an entity is obvious, but is there anything else?

Comment: @ireddick - There's also Create, Update and Delete, but these are a different set, as they don't render a page but rather perform some action and then redirect. There might be different view and edit variations, though, later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the default IPageFactory with org.apache.wicket.settings.ISessionSettings.setPageFactory(IPageFactory) and use different strategy of instantiating the page if it is special one.

Comment: Would I do that in the `init()` method of my application class?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an EntityPage and implement the differences within your panels, but then you'd need a lot of similar panels (or a few generic panels if they don't really differ). Or you could take a look at one of the rapid prototyping libraries for wicket like [wicketopia](http://wicketopia.sourceforge.net/). I wouldn't consider any of them (the ones I found and tested) to be production-ready but they can be salvaged for ideas *g*.

Comment: Without knowing anything more specific of the problem, I'd go with panels too.